# What is the correct pattern to get data in reactjs with the flux architecture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I am creating a `flux` app with `react` for my views.  Here is my code for my view

```
function getUsers() {
  return {
    users: UserStore.getUsers()
  };
}

var UsersList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return getUsers();
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        UserStore.addChangeListener(this.onChange);
    },
    onChange: function() {
        this.setState(getUsers());
    },
    render: function() {
        ...
    }
});

module.exports = UsersList;
```

My `getUsers` happens in my store.  Here is that code:

```
getUsers: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/users',
    }).success(function(data) {
        users = data.users;
        that.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    });
    return users;
}
```

What ends up happening is I get stuck in an infinite loop.  I go out and get my `users`, it then `emits` a change event and which then calls my `onChange` again, which starts the loop over.  What would be the proper way to make do this with `flux`?  What are the patterns that others are using?

Comment: Slightly unrelated (apologies) but please refrain from using the outdated `var that = this` paradigm.  Where possible you should use `function() {}.bind(this)` instead.  The react library itself requires `Function.prototype.bind` in order to run, older browsers are already required to have a polyfil for react to work in them so when using react there's really no reason not to use `.bind()`.

Answer (score 2):

The act of retrieving data from the store should not trigger another retrieval of data from the server.

I'd try storing your users locally in the store, and putting your ajax call into a separate WebAPIUtils module that you can call from action creator methods.

So in that scenario, `getUsers()` in the store retrieves data from a private _users collection internal to the store.  The `WebAPIUtils.getUsers()` method would call for the data from the server.

In a AppBootstrap module you would do this:

```
// create an INIT action
ActionCreators.initialize(WebAPIUtils.getUsers());
```

The UserStore would respond to INIT by initializing the _users collection, and the emit 'change'.

The UsersList component would then receive the data from the store by calling UserStore.getUsers().

At some point, someone (by clicking a submit button) or something (like a timer) would call for new data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem. Hoping the React team updates the TodoMVC tutorial to show how the app works when there are already todo items that exist when the page loads.

I expect there's a more proper way of handling this, but until I see one, the way I'm handling it is to add a flag in the Store that checks whether `_users` is empty, and if so, only `return` the data without emitting the change event.